# Eigen Library: Sorting matrix rows not working on dynamic-sized matrices

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to sort the rows of an Eigen matrix (or block) by column values, and it works when the matrix is fixed-size but not when the matrix is dynamic-size.

The code below does not work when commenting the first line:

```
#define FIXED_SIZE_MMM

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

namespace Eigen {
    template<class T>
    void swap(T&& a, T&& b){
        a.swap(b);
    }
}

void sortRowsByColumn(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXi> mat, int col)
{    
    std::sort(  mat.rowwise().begin(), 
                mat.rowwise().end(),
                [col](auto const& r1, auto const& r2)
                {
                    return r1(col) < r2(col);
                } );
}

int main(){

    #ifdef FIXED_SIZE_MMM
    Eigen::Matrix4i A;
    A.Random();
    #else
    Eigen::MatrixXi A;
    A.resize(4,4);
    A.Random();
    #endif

    std::cout << "before sorting:\n" << A << "\n";

    sortRowsByColumn(A.topRows(3),3);

    std::cout << "sorted:\n" << A << "\n";

}
```

Thanks for any help : )

Comment: Here the code:

https://godbolt.org/z/1GhToE7oK

Comment: Try `A.setRandom();` And it appears to work: https://godbolt.org/z/5qfjfPTYx (I changed the column, since the top 3 rows were already sorted by the last column)

Comment: Are you sure you are on Eigen version 3.4.0 (or an up-to-date devel branch)? Did you pass any different compiler flags on your machine vs on godbolt?

Comment: I found the issue. I had an Eigen version mix-up problem that I had not realized. Now with fresh 3.4 it works well. Thanks again!